# reducing relative clause using prefer verb

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

I was curious to know what kind of reduction has used for the word "preferring" in the following sentence.

I think punctuation is not correct. I guess it originally had been ", because they(students) prefer...". in which case it does not require a comma.

> This questionable answer claims that electronic devices can be addictive. One consequence of this is school children might not be able to do their homework, preferring to socialize online...

Comment: Syntactically, your adverbial clause *(**preferring to socialize online**)* is no different to, for example, *He could not answer, **being ignorant**.* Such clauses can often be relocated to different positions within an utterance (yours, for example, could be moved to before or after ***school children***). But note that although *normally* they're set off with commas, that doesn't really reflect a "grammatical rule" as such. If it's possible to *speak* the utterance without pauses you don't need commas (I personally could accept *He being ignorant couldn't answer* with neither; YMMV).

Comment: There's no reduction. The non-finite clause "preferring to socialize online" is a gerund-participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Such supplements are normally set apart by a comma in writing and a slight pause in speech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One consequence of this is [that] school children, who prefer to socialize online, might not be able to do their homework."
, 
The punctuation of the sentence you quoted is correct, and it's a clearer way to express the idea than the unreduced version because of the continuing nature of the "preferring", and because the important fact of missing homework is presented first, and the explanation second.

Comment: Thank you @jack-oflaherty. Does this means we can move relative clause to other place in the sentence? if yes, would you mind giving me a reference or something because I have never this before

Comment: Per my comment above, you could move *your* adverbial clause to before or after ***school children***, but you ***can't*** move it all the way to before ***One consequence of this***, because that's too far away from the target noun associated with the clause.

Comment: En glish, yes, we can move it, as long as it doesn't make things hard to read. I don't have a reference at hand to offer you.